# Return value from Azure MobileServices.InvokeApi

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

So Im trying to get a value from my appsettings from azure it successfully returns the value but Im trying to return that value.  Bear with me Im kind of new to javascript here is the code.

```
function getAppSettings(mobilesvc, appSettings){
 var appSettingsValue;

    mobilesvc.invokeApi(appSettings, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function (results) {
       var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(results.responseText);
       appSettingsValue = jsonResponse;      
    }, function (error) {
    });

    return appSettingsValue;
}
```

When I call the getAppSettings function it returns an undefined but within the "promise" if I add a console.log it shows the results.  Any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: that's because `GET` request is asynchronous, you need to implement a callback.

Comment: Thanks Sudhansu,  what I ended up doing was using angular "factory" getAppSettings: function (mobilesvc, appSettings) {
                return mobilesvc.invokeApi(appSettings, {
                    method: 'GET'
                }).then(function (results) {
                    return results;
                }, function (error) { });
            }  it was finally able to return the value

Comment: Oh! were you using Angular, should have tagged it with Angular JS.
Cool! did it work?

Comment: If that worked, you should post it as the answer and mark as Answered so others can easily see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use angular "factory" `getAppSettings: function (mobilesvc, appSettings) { return mobilesvc.invokeApi(appSettings, { method: 'GET' }).then(function (results) { return results; }, function (error) { }); }` and it should finally be able to return the value. :)